# Manejo de listas en python

Tags: python

Quiero hacer una pequeña aplicación en python, que lo que hacer es estar en segundo plano escuchando los mensajes que recibe, para reenviarlos a otro array.

Tengo un diccionario de esta forma:

```
from_to_redir = {
  "1447316562" : 1487212331,  # 1-2
  "1317723051" : 1308241218,  # 3-4
  "1287749122" : 1187924740,  # 5-6
  "1473192810" : 1197543096,  #7-8
  "1303515012" : 1330012567,  #9-10
  "1231992215" : 1262349386,  #11-12
  "1268998802" : 1411154699,  #13-14
  "1490320978" : 1402311342,  #15-16
  "1499511191" : 1246354970   #17-18
}
```

El print de from_to_redir imprime esto:

```
{1447316562: 1487212331, 1317723051: 1308241218, 1287749122: 1187924740, 1473192810: 1197543096, 1303515012: 1330012567, 1231992215: 1262349386, 1268998802: 1411154699, 1490320978: 1402311342, 1499511191: 1246354970}
```

Ahora mismo solo trato de que funcionen cada uno de los reenvíos del array, cada grupo de números ("1447316562") hace referencia a un chat, donde llegan las notificaciones de mis sensores, el número de al lado, indica a donde tienen que redirigír esos mensajes.

Mi problema viene, y no se si es por culpa de la programación o de las limitaciones de python, que al llegar ala linea del array que pone (9-10) ya no reenvía nada, es como si rompiera, como si no fuera capaz de llegar hasta el final del array, y realmente no es que esté cada uno de los chats recibiendo constantemente, en verdad es de vez en cuando, pero no lo logro.

Y me gustaría usar este modelo de proyecto, por el tema de la facilidad a la hora de añadir mas sensores.

Muchas gracias por su atención, se agradece cualquier aportación que puedan brindarme.

Un saludo.

Comment: Creo que lo que realmente tienes es un diccionario y no una lista, ¿no?

Comment: Bien visto, realmente si, me da igual como plantearlo en verdad, me parecio util tenerlo en un fichero que pudiera modificar a mi gusto, lo llame array por generalizar..

Comment: Prueba a imprimir la variable `redirections` justo después de inicializarla a ver qué tiene. Quizás algunas de las claves del diccionario han sido considaradas strings en lugar de enteros (y por cierto, ¿no deberían ser strings? Me extraña que uses enteros tan grandes, igual alguno se te puede salir de rango). O quizás no estás leyendo la clave corecta (¿se llama `from_to_redir` o `from_to_redir_1`? Por otro lado, yo cambiaría el título de la pregunta pues poco tiene que ver con arrays python, y más con yaml o con tu framwork asincrono.

Comment: El entero que ves, es un identificador unico asignado automaticamente, si imprimo la variable redirections, me imprime tal cual el diccionario, ya lo probe, con lo cual lo lee entero, edito y lo pongo, el problema viene cuando intenta leerlo en bucle, por otor lado, el nombre del diccionario es from_to_redir, pero hice pruebas partiendolo en varios diccionarios, espero explcarme correctamente. Gracias por tu sugerencia del titulo @abulafia

Comment: @Peisou ¿Dónde está ese procesamiento en bucle del diccionario? Yo no veo ningún bucle que itere sobre el diccionario... Lo que veo es un manejador de eventos que usa ese diccionario para acceder a una clave concreta. El único bucle que hay es el bucle de eventos del _framework_ (¿cuál es, por cierto? ¿`telethon`?). No acabo de entender el problema exactamente. ¿Es que cuando recibes un evento por el canal `1303515012` esperas que se reenvíe a `1330012567` y eso no ocurre?

Comment: Correcto, es telethon, y es justamente lo que espero, y lo hace, pero con 3 o 4 canales solamente, pense en hacer yo un bucle manual, pero los propios metodos que me proporciona ya me hace toda la funcionalidad que necesito, de hecho esta confirmado que ese codigo funciona siempre, pero no con tantos canales.

Comment: ¿tendrá que ver con algún límite que te imponga el servidor en cuanto a número de canales abiertos? Iba a decir que también pudiera ser que para manejar los mensajes hubiera por debajo un _pool_ de hilos y que el número de hilos limitara el número de canales, pero no creo que sea el caso porque está tabajando con `async/await`, que implica que todo se puede hacer desde un único hilo. En todo caso, en mi opinión no se trata de ningún problema con python y el diccionario, sino con limitaciones del _framework_ o del servicio.

Comment: @Peisou Prueba a activar el modo DEBUG (como explica [aqui](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extra/troubleshooting/enable-logging.html)) para ver mensajes del protocolo telegram subyacente, a ver si encuentras que el servidor te está enviando algún tipo de error que explique por qué no funciona como esperas.

Comment: hare debug y probare, si no tendre que pensar otra forma de plantear el programa, porque incluso cree varios clientes ( o hilos) para manejar los dijerentes diccionarios que cree en el yml) Vere tambien si en vez de usando un diccionario, puedo ir haciendo que lea y envie uno por uno, aunque me parece tedioso ademas de poco practico, pero bueno mientras me funcione. Gracias por tus aportaciones, editare si encuentro o me choco con algo interesante.

Comment: @abulafia he leido la doc, tanto de telethon como la de python, y lo de activar el log, no me sirve realmente, porque no me saca los errores del framework, me tira los errores que yo le programe que diga, o eso es lo que entiendo..

Comment: @Peisou Es para mostrar tus propios mensajes, o configurar cómo los muestra otro módulo que importes. El problema es que según dice telethon, el manejador de log que telethon instala por defecto es `NullHandler`, que no muestra nada. Quizás tengas que hacer `logger = logging.getLogger('telethon')` y luego lo que se muestra [aqui](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/logging/#example-configuration-directly-in-code), (excepto la línea que asigna la variable `logger` al principio, pues ya le hemos asignado con el logger de telethon).

Comment: @abulafia lo he conseguido solucionar, publico la solución.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tras investigar y leer muchos logs, he conseguido saber que tipo de error devolvía, he visto que no era culpa del programa, ni del diccionario, ni de las limitaciones de la API, si no un fallo de uso.

Cuando recibía los mensajes en los canales pertinentes, los mensajes los cogía correctamente, pero a la hora de reenviarlos, me decía que no podia encontrar el channel_id que yo le había establecido en el diccionario.

Debuggeando averigüe, que telethon en su "lógica" asigna un id distinto, al de telegram, a los chats, con lo cual tube que hacer un getUpdates de los dialogs( mensajes entrantes ) y si el id del canal, corresponde con el diccionario, que buscase el id correspondiente, haciendo esto he conseguido que funcione a la perfección.

Gracias por los comentarios, sin su ayuda no lo habría logrado.